# How to make a score counter for my Android app

Tags: android

I'm quite a beginner with java and Android in general so I would like to ask how to easily make a score counter that would change every millisecond, so every millisecond they survive the score counter moves up 1. 
Something like
[this](http://d2fhka9tf2vaj2.cloudfront.net/tuts/062_scoreClass/Tutorial/15.jpg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are not talking about building the UI. Here's how you can use a `TimerTask`: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

Comment: What do you mean? "System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime" gives you elapsed seconds. Set that on to your TextView! Am I missing something?

And mark the question as answered please.